# How to edit text in svg image

Tags: html, css, xml, svg

I have a svg logo named:WORLDTIME

code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="186px" height="19px" viewBox="0 0 186 19" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <!-- Generator: Sketch 63.1 (92452) - https://sketch.com -->
    <title>Worldtime_logo@1x</title>
    <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
    <g id="WorldTime" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <path d="M10.634,18.694 L13.182,7.332 L15.73,18.694 L22.074,18.694 L26.364,0.286 L20.852,0.286 L18.824,12.818 L15.964,0.286 L10.374,0.286 L7.54,12.818 L5.512,0.286 L0,0.286 L4.29,18.694 L10.634,18.694 Z M40.9854545,18.876 C42.7014545,18.876 44.2744545,18.473 45.7044545,17.667 C47.1344545,16.861 48.2654545,15.7386667 49.0974545,14.3 C49.9294545,12.8613333 50.3454545,11.2406667 50.3454545,9.438 C50.3454545,7.63533333 49.9337879,6.01466667 49.1104545,4.576 C48.2871212,3.13733333 47.1604545,2.015 45.7304545,1.209 C44.3004545,0.403 42.7187879,0 40.9854545,0 C39.2694545,0 37.6921212,0.403 36.2534545,1.209 C34.8147879,2.015 33.6794545,3.13733333 32.8474545,4.576 C32.0154545,6.01466667 31.5994545,7.63533333 31.5994545,9.438 C31.5994545,11.2406667 32.0154545,12.8613333 32.8474545,14.3 C33.6794545,15.7386667 34.8147879,16.861 36.2534545,17.667 C37.6921212,18.473 39.2694545,18.876 40.9854545,18.876 Z M40.9854545,14.118 C39.6854545,14.118 38.6627879,13.6933333 37.9174545,12.844 C37.1721212,11.9946667 36.7994545,10.8593333 36.7994545,9.438 C36.7994545,7.982 37.1721212,6.83366667 37.9174545,5.993 C38.6627879,5.15233333 39.6854545,4.732 40.9854545,4.732 C42.2854545,4.732 43.3037879,5.15233333 44.0404545,5.993 C44.7771212,6.83366667 45.1454545,7.982 45.1454545,9.438 C45.1454545,10.8593333 44.7727879,11.9946667 44.0274545,12.844 C43.2821212,13.6933333 42.2681212,14.118 40.9854545,14.118 Z M61.3009091,18.694 L61.3009091,11.908 L61.8209091,11.908 L65.5389091,18.694 L71.1809091,18.694 L66.9949091,11.544 C68.3295758,11.1626667 69.3522424,10.4996667 70.0629091,9.555 C70.7735758,8.61033333 71.1289091,7.49666667 71.1289091,6.214 C71.1289091,5.08733333 70.8689091,4.07333333 70.3489091,3.172 C69.8289091,2.27066667 69.0532424,1.56433333 68.0219091,1.053 C66.9905758,0.541666667 65.7382424,0.286 64.2649091,0.286 L64.2649091,0.286 L56.1789091,0.286 L56.1789091,18.694 L61.3009091,18.694 Z M63.8229091,8.476 L61.3009091,8.476 L61.3009091,4.602 L63.8229091,4.602 C64.5335758,4.602 65.0665758,4.77533333 65.4219091,5.122 C65.7772424,5.46866667 65.9549091,5.94533333 65.9549091,6.552 C65.9549091,7.83466667 65.2442424,8.476 63.8229091,8.476 L63.8229091,8.476 Z M87.5703636,18.694 L87.5703636,14.82 L81.8243636,14.82 L81.8243636,0.286 L76.7023636,0.286 L76.7023636,18.694 L87.5703636,18.694 Z M100.371818,18.694 C102.313152,18.694 104.003152,18.2953333 105.441818,17.498 C106.880485,16.7006667 107.989818,15.6043333 108.769818,14.209 C109.549818,12.8136667 109.939818,11.2233333 109.939818,9.438 C109.939818,7.65266667 109.554152,6.06666667 108.782818,4.68 C108.011485,3.29333333 106.902152,2.21433333 105.454818,1.443 C104.007485,0.671666667 102.313152,0.286 100.371818,0.286 L100.371818,0.286 L93.0398182,0.286 L93.0398182,18.694 L100.371818,18.694 Z M99.9038182,14.118 L98.1618182,14.118 L98.1618182,4.758 L99.9038182,4.758 C101.411818,4.758 102.599152,5.16966667 103.465818,5.993 C104.332485,6.81633333 104.765818,7.96466667 104.765818,9.438 C104.765818,10.9286667 104.332485,12.0813333 103.465818,12.896 C102.599152,13.7106667 101.411818,14.118 99.9038182,14.118 L99.9038182,14.118 Z M124.665273,18.694 L124.665273,4.368 L129.631273,4.368 L129.631273,0.286 L114.655273,0.286 L114.655273,4.368 L119.569273,4.368 L119.569273,18.694 L124.665273,18.694 Z M139.988727,18.694 L139.988727,0.286 L134.866727,0.286 L134.866727,18.694 L139.988727,18.694 Z M151.490182,18.694 L151.490182,8.294 L154.896182,18.694 L159.290182,18.694 L162.696182,8.294 L162.696182,18.694 L167.766182,18.694 L167.766182,0.364 L161.552182,0.364 L157.158182,12.272 L152.634182,0.364 L146.368182,0.364 L146.368182,18.694 L151.490182,18.694 Z M186.001636,18.694 L186.001636,14.612 L179.267636,14.612 L179.267636,11.284 L185.221636,11.284 L185.221636,7.41 L179.267636,7.41 L179.267636,4.368 L186.001636,4.368 L186.001636,0.286 L174.145636,0.286 L174.145636,18.694 L186.001636,18.694 Z" id="Worldtime_logo" fill="#FFFFFF" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

my question is how can I convert the word from WORDTIME to TRUTHTIME,is there any tool that I can use?

Comment: Thank you for your reply,I'm not sure,I'm using pycharm to code,and already tried some online editor but still not work.

Comment: Yes,but I have no idea how to edit it,so that I can get TRUTHTIME ,that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Ahh the word is a path. You'll need to use an SVG editor and draw a new path. Inkscape perhaps.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

### as metioned in comments,text is stored as svg path and you can edit it with a svg editor app.

but if you understand how svg convert strings to path,may you be able to detect your text path and simply change it. searching in google may help you a lot.